# Placeholder Remove at build time constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

Xcode Interface Builder has the checkbox `"Placeholder - Remove at build time"` within the Attributes Inspector of a autolayout constraint.

[image: IB Size Inspector screenshot]

I googled but could not find a satisfactory answer.

- What is a "Placeholder" constraint?
- What does "Remove at build time" mean?
- Why is this useful? (An example would be helpful)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "Remove at build time" option allows you to provide a Placeholder constraint for a view.

For example, suppose you are calculating the view's height and then applying a constraint programmatically, then there might be possibility of having a compile time error in the interface builder that you haven't provided view's height constraint that was expected.

But if you provide a placeholder height (by using 'remove at build time' option) while designing a view in the interface builder then it will not show an error and remove this placeholder constraint as soon as the interface builder builds.

Comment: That can be done with intrinsic size property in storyboard

Comment: 'Intrinsic content size' is a different property which defines any view's default size but 'remove at build time' is something else and not related to 'intrinsic content size'.

Comment: What I am trying to say is what you have explained that can also  done with intrinsic size then why to use remove at build time ?

Comment: UIView has no intrinsic size it's depend on his sub views, Empty image view has also zero  intrinsic size. so we need add temporary constrain with remove on build time  to fix error of story board the temporary constrain will not apply on build time

Comment: It is only used for design purpose, satisfy interface builder. 
No effect when after application run. 
Am I r8 ?

Comment: @ShourobDatta: absolutely